# How To Search the Word In Textarea

Tags: java, search, jtextarea

I want to Highlight The word from Caret Position to End of The Textarea then Highlight the word from Starting of the textarea to end then repeat the process in circular manner.My code works for current caret position to end of the textarea only.Please check it once.

My Code:

```
public void highLightWholeWord(JTextArea component, String patteren) {
try {
    Document doc = component.getDocument();
    String text = component.getText(0, doc.getLength());
    int pos = component.getCaretPosition();
    boolean found = false;
    int findLength = patteren.length();
    // Rest the search position if we're at the end of the document
    if (pos + findLength > doc.getLength()) {
        pos = 0;
    }
    while (pos + findLength <= doc.getLength()) {
        // Extract the text from teh docuemnt
        String match = doc.getText(pos, findLength).toLowerCase();
        // Check to see if it matches or request
        if (match.equals(patteren)) {
            if (pos - 1 >= 0
                        && Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(pos - 1, 1).charAt(0))
                                        || Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(findLength, 1).charAt(0))) {
                if (pos + findLength == doc.getLength()
                                             || Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(pos + findLength, 1).charAt(0))) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        pos++;
    }
    if (found) {
    component.setSelectionStart(pos);
    component.setSelectionEnd(pos + patteren.length());
    component.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
    }
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you edit your question and show examples of text and where you expect it to be highlighted (you can use **bold** to simulate selection).

Comment: if(found) loop Highlight the pattern word.My code highlight the search word from current caret position(courser position) to end of the textarea.But,my requirement is search word highlight from caret pos to end of the textarea then from start of the textarea to end then continue this way(Circular manner).

Comment: Your code only highlights one word. And it's highlighting it to the end of the word, not to the end of the textarea. I don't see anything that highlights more than one word. So some code is missing. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Ya,At a time it's highlight the one word.when I click on FindNext Button then it highlights next occurrence of search word.In this way till the end of the textarea is happen.But,I want after the end start highlight from start not stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see a text for example, and suppose we are searching for the word "xxx". Suppose the last time you clicked the button it selected the last xxx:

> xxx ttt aaa xxx fff xxx yyy **xxx** zzz

The size of this text is 35 characters.

Now, the caret position is at the end of the highlighted xxx (position 31). And the pattern length is 3. You have an if condition that says:

```
if (pos + findLength > doc.getLength()) {
    pos = 0;
}
```

Now, `pos + findLength` is `31+3` which is `34`. So it is **not** greater than `doc.getLength()`. So it will not set `pos = 0`.

So you will start searching for `xxx` from position 31, but there is no more `xxx` there. Just `zzz`. Eventually you'll reach the end of the document and `found` will not be set. So the selection will not be changed, and the caret will stay in position 31.

So no matter how many times you press the button, the same thing will happen.

This means that your condition for setting `pos=0` is wrong. It will only work if the `xxx` is absolutely the last word.

Here is a suggestion to solve this:

Define your condition in another method:

```
public boolean foundPattern( Document doc, int pos, int findLength  ) {
    String match = doc.getText(pos, findLength).toLowerCase();
    // Check to see if it matches or request
    if (match.equals(patteren)) {
        if (pos - 1 >= 0
                    && Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(pos - 1, 1).charAt(0))
                                    || Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(findLength, 1).charAt(0))) {
            if (pos + findLength == doc.getLength()
                                         || Character.isWhitespace(doc.getText(pos + findLength, 1).charAt(0))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is just to make writing the actual while part easier:

```
while (pos + findLength <= doc.getLength()) {

   found = foundPattern( doc, pos, findLength );

   if ( found ) {
      break;
   }

   pos++;

}

if ( ! found ) {
   pos = 0;

   while ( pos + findLength < component.getCaretPosition() ) {
       found = foundPattern( doc, pos, findLength );
       if ( found ) {
          break;
       }

       pos++;
   }
}
```

So now you have two loops. If the first doesn't find the pattern (from caret position to end of document), then the second one starts looking from start of document to caret position.